# How can I code a customized set of commands for a Telegram Bot Keyboard in Java?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

So I looked at this example of a bot the mafia gang which I am a fan of, and their Custom keyboard amazed me:

[image]

I found out that I have to add this Simple Java API for Telegram Bots jar in order to implement it. I did add the jar, but I dint know how to go about it. I would want to create the custom keyboard using Java. This is the source code :

```
public class Pizza {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Pizza.class.getName());

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramLongPollingBot() {

            @Override
            public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
                Message message = update.getMessage();
                Long chatId = message.getChatId();
                String input = message.getText();
                if ("/recommend".equals(input)) {
                    SendMessage request = new SendMessage();
                    request.setChatId(chatId.toString());
                    request.setText("Peperoni");
                    try {
                        sendMessage(request);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not send message", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String getBotUsername() {
                return "USERNAME_BOT";
            }

            @Override
            public String getBotToken() {
                return "BOT_TOKEN";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which java telegram API are you using?

Comment: am using this java telegram api https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

Comment: @Menasheh is it possible to come up with a source code that can create the following Keyboard. Thanks

Comment: Which keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some samples of usage for this library at https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBotsExample. More exactly, you can check custom keybaords at https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBotsExample/blob/master/src/main/java/org/telegram/updateshandlers/WeatherHandlers.java ([@weatherbot](https://telegram.me/weatherbot)).

Inside that file, you can see, for example that the settings keyboard is generated with the following method:

```
private static ReplyKeyboardMarkup getSettingsKeyboard(String language) {
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboad(false);

    List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    KeyboardRow keyboardFirstRow = new KeyboardRow();
    keyboardFirstRow.add(getLanguagesCommand(language));
    keyboardFirstRow.add(getUnitsCommand(language));
    KeyboardRow keyboardSecondRow = new KeyboardRow();
    keyboardSecondRow.add(getAlertsCommand(language));
    keyboardSecondRow.add(getBackCommand(language));
    keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
    keyboard.add(keyboardSecondRow);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);

    return replyKeyboardMarkup;
}
```

You can use that ReplyKeyboardMarkup inside the `SendMessage` method like:

```
    SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
    message.enableMarkdown(true);
    message.setReplyMarkup(getSettingsKeyboard(language));
    message.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
    message.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
    message.setText(getSettingsMessage(language));
```

Comment: great let me try this on my source code and i will tell you.
Thanks bro